# Use GIT LFS to track a large binary file without a file extension

Tags: ios, git, github, git-lfs

Inside iOS frameworks is a binary that has no extension. My binary exceeds github's size limit of 100MB.

- I've set up LFS as indicated [here](https://git-lfs.github.com/?utm_source=github_site&utm_medium=pricing_learnmore_link&utm_campaign=gitlfs)
- I've tried to tell LFS to track my binary by name: `git lfs track 'MyFramework'`
- I've tried to tell LFS to track my binary by path: `git lfs track 'path/to/MyFramework'`
- No deal either way! Github server still responds by telling me that the file is too large.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In git-lfs v1.1.1, the tracking such as `git lfs track 'path/MyFramework'` works well. You can check whether or not git-lfs track the file correctly with 'ls-files'.

```
$ git lfs ls-files
828a9ca55c * path/MyFramework
```

If git already tracks the file, git-lfs doesn't track it. I think you have to remove tracking `MyFramework` file, and then add `git lfs track ..`, and then commit it again.

Comment: "If git already tracks the file, git-lfs doesn't track it." That's the ticket, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some notes for people who find this:

- As Outsider said, you have to add the file to GIT LFS before adding it to GIT:`git lfs track 'path/to/file`
- If file is already in GIT, you need to remove it first. If you've already committed the file locally to GIT in the past, you have a legitimate issue. You won't be able to commit your local deletion of the file, as the remote repo will first need to have the file before deleting it. I worked around this by reverting my repo to a state before the large file existed, using the command listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718540/869838). If you can't do that, you'll have to solve this issue some other way. GIT is infinitely flexible, albeit opaque...
- Before `git lfs-ls-files` will confirm that LFS is tracking your file, you must add the file to actual GIT: `git add someFile`
- My GIT client (Gitbox) doesn't seem to know how to deal with GIT LFS, so I needed (at least the first time) to add, commit and push (see [here](https://git-lfs.github.com/)) on the command line.

Comment: Can you expand on this statement? `You won't be able to commit your local deletion of the file, as the remote repo will first need to have the file before deleting it.`. I don't understand why a simple revert of the commit that added the file wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find the solution to this for a while and every answer was to use `git lfs track ..` Which is great for single files, but doesn't handle new files being added.

Adding this to the .gitattributes file worked for finding everything that doesn't have an extension in a Repo:

```
* filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text # Include everything
/**/ -filter=lfs -diff=lfs -merge=lfs -text # Exclude directories
*.* -filter=lfs -diff=lfs -merge=lfs -text # Exclude anything with an extension
```